# Consigo colocar uma pergunta, e depois que ela for respondida aparece outra usando apenas JS?

Tags: javascript

Queria que aparecesse no meu código usando apenas JS o seguinte contexto:

Bem Vindo!

Verificação automática do dia de hoje (se menor que X permitir continuar, se não encerrar)

Qual sua data de nascimento ? Resposta X (se maior que X permitir, se  não encerrar)

**(Eu consegui fazer daqui em diante)**

Verificar quantidade de participantes ( se menor que 100 permitir continuar, se não encerrar)

Aparecer lista de participantes e palestrantes

```js
/*Feito: "Enquanto a quantidade de participantes for inferior a 100, permitir cadastro; senão, alertar que o cadastro não será permitido por ter excedido o limite."*/

let listaDeParticipantes = ["Helena", "Chico", "Mário", "José", "Maria"];
let quantidadeDeParticipantes = listaDeParticipantes.length;

if (quantidadeDeParticipantes < 100) {
    listaDeParticipantes.push("João");
    console.log(listaDeParticipantes);

if (quantidadeDeParticipantes > 100) {

/*Se não passar de 100 participantes aparece a frase de baixo.*/
} else {
       console.log("Suas inscrições foram feitas com sucesso! Veja a seguir o nome dos palestrantes do evento!");
}   

/*Se passar de 100 participantes aparece a frase de baixo.*/    
} else {
    console.log("Quantidade de participantes atingiu o limite.");
}

/*Lista de Palestrantes Inicio*/
let listaDePalestrantes = [" ","Linus Torvalds, Considerado o pai do Linux e criador do Git!", "Brendan Eich, Criador do JavaScript", "Noah Glass, criador do logo do GitHub e da primeiro logo do Twitter"];

let quantidadeDePalestrantes = listaDePalestrantes.length;
let inicio = 0;

do {
    console.log(listaDePalestrantes[inicio]);
    inicio++;
} while (inicio < quantidadeDePalestrantes);
/*Lista de Palestrantes Final*/
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lucas, você pode fazer algo parecido com isso, veja se funciona, só acrescentar a lógica dos if's:

```
const vetor=  ['Heloisa', 'Lucas'];
const mensagem = 'Suas inscrições foram feitas com sucesso!'

const readline = require("readline");
const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});

rl.question("Qual é a sua data de Nascimento?? ", function(ano) {


    rl.question("Qual o seu nome? ", function(nome) {

        vetor.push(nome)
        console.log(`${vetor}, ${mensagem}`);
        rl.close();
    });
});
```

o readline faz parte do nodeJS, pode dar uma aprofundada depois se quiser:
https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html

mas basicamente ele está fazendo o que o prompt faria se você tivesse rodando esse código no navegador, o prompt é um comando que roda uma questão por vez para o usuário, e só passa para a outra depois que ele responde (e dependendo da resposta se você acrescentar uma lógica ai).